# kdb+: use string as variable name

Tags: kdb

How can I use a string as a variable name?

I want my variable name to be constructed during runtime, but how can I use it as a left argument and assign a value to it?

Example:

```
[`$"test"] : 1              / 'assign error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use "set" but it will create a global:

```
q){(`$"test") set 1;test}[]
1
q)test
1
```

or (as noted by [user2393012](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393012/user2393012) in the comments):

```
@[`.;`test;:;1]
```

If you want to avoid globals you could use some sort of namespace/dictionary/mapping:

```
q){d:()!();d[`$"test"]:1;d`test}[]
1
```

Comment: Re the latter one - generic way is @ apply on namespace - very useful! `@[\`.;\`test;:;1]`

Comment: This still creates a global though - just to be clear

Answer (score 1):

Provided `.data` exists, Amend At does the job:

```
q)@[`.data;`test;:;1]       / .data not defined
'type
  [0]  @[`.data;`test;:;1]
       ^
q).data.foo: 42             / defined .data
q)@[`.data;`$"test";:;1]
`.data
q).data.test
1
```