# kdb - passing in a symbol as parameter for variable name

Tags: kdb

I've been trying to pass in a symbol from a process outside KDB and am wishing to use this symbol to create a variable where we then load a specific file in case it doesn't exist.

```
//create some sample data and write to disk
.data.area52.varName1: ([] name:`billy`allen`terry; val:90 100 200);
.data.area52.varName2: 10 #200; 
.data.area53.varName1: 9 #100; 
.data.area53.varName2: ([] name:`joe`jim`bob; val:10 20 30);
.data.area53.varName3: `random;
`:area52 set .data.area52;
`:area53 set .data.area52;
```

I am trying to pass in the parameter for reference `area52`for example which will test a conditional if it exists (do nothing, else) then create the variable loading via`` get `:area52 ``

First, I wrote a conditional below which seems to check (however trhe  `` `.areaXX `` isn't parametrized yet.

```
 // fresh instance of KDB
.data.area52: $[`area52 in key `.data; .data.area52;  get `:area52
```

And then stumbled onto the link here  [kdb+: use string as variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876939/kdb-use-string-as-variable-name)
Which gets me most of the way there.

Is there a way to parameterize the beginning of the lambda below passing in some combination of  `` `.area52 `` ?   Much of this variable can be assembled / edited outside KDB and only passing in the

for an example, we can have several hundred   `` `.areaXX ``  that we could pass into KDB as data is changed and refreshed.

```
{.data.area52:()!(); @[`.data; `area52;:; (get `:area52)]} [];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To safeguard against the situation where the namespace `.data` doesn't exist you could use the following lambda which takes parameter `area52` as an argument.

```
q){(` sv ``data,x) set ()!(); @[`.data; x; :; get hsym x]}`area52
`.data
```

Tying it back to the original problem, this lambda will create the variable if it does not exist by reading from the file of the same name:

```
/ .data does not exist yet
q).data
'.data
  [0]  .data
       ^

/ create variable if necessary
q){if[not x in key `.data; (` sv ``data,x)set get hsym x]}`area52

/ check .data
q).data
      | ::
area52| ``varName1`varName2!(::;+`name`val!(`billy`allen`terry;90 100 200);20..
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, will have a deep dive we had a look at another method in JS which allows us to pass things in alright.  We've settled on keeping .data as a common namespace which should save us some overhead.  Thx!

Comment: Thomas, this is perfect, thank you again. Tested it again this morning and its super. Appreciate the guidance. We are at least preserving the data namespace so we'll have access to that.